# El código no reconoce una const

Tags: javascript

**Contexto:**

¡Buenas!
Estoy trabajando sobre una API de la plataforma RAGE MP (plataforma multiplayer alternativa de GTA V, vamos, para un servidor de Roleplay entre amigos).

Estoy intentando hacer un sistema de vehículos, es decir, cuando tu creas un vehículo permanente que se almacenen sus datos en la base de datos, y al iniciar el servidor que todos los vehículos de la base de datos aparezcan en su última ubicación.

A continuación dejo el código en JavaScript y el problema que tengo.

**Código:**

```
// SPAWNEO DE VEHÍCULOS.

try {
    const arrValue = misc.query('SELECT vid, modelo, pos, heading, dimension FROM vehiculos');

    arrValue.forEach(data => {
        mp.vehicles.new(mp.joaat(data.modelo), new mp.Vector3(data.x, data.y, data.z), {
            heading: data.heading,
            dimension: data.dimension
        });
    });

    misc.log.info('Se han cargado exitosamente los vehículos.');

} catch (error) {
    console.error('\u001b[31m[ERROR; SISTEMA DE VEHÍCULOS] ' + error);
}

function newFunction(arrValue) {
    arrValue.forEach(data => {
        mp.vehicles.new(mp.joaat(data.modelo), new mp.Vector3(data.x, data.y, data.z), {
            heading: data.heading,
            dimension: data.dimension
        });
    });
}
```

**El problema que tengo es el siguiente:**

Al ejecutar el servidor me salta un error por el try y catch que dice lo siguiente;

```
[ERROR; SISTEMA DE VEHÍCULOS] TypeError: arrValue.forEach is not a function
```

Entonces, los vehículos almacenados en la base de datos no aparecen en el juego, me imagino que es por ese error.

A continuación, voy a dejar una imagen de la base de datos.

[image: Base de datos]

Llevo **un mes literalmente** intentando arreglar esto y no lo logro, he buscado mil y una alternativas de hacerlo y creo que esta es la más aproximada.

Perdón por los errores que puedan llegar a haber, estoy aprendiendo en este mundillo.

¡Gracias!

**Añadiendo console.log(arrValue);**

Ahora el error dice lo siguiente;

```
[INFO] Loading NodeJS packages...
Promise { <pending> }
[ERROR; SISTEMA DE VEHÍCULOS] TypeError: arrValue.forEach is not a function
[DONE] "RP" package has been loaded.
[INFO] Starting packages...
[DONE] Server packages have been started.
[DONE] Started resource transfer server at 22006 port.
[DONE] Client-side packages weight: 1.301254 MB (uncompressed: 2.980871 MB).
[INFO] Initializing networking...
[DONE] Networking has been started: (IPv4-only) at 25.4.21.140:22005
[DONE] The server is ready to accept connections.
LA BASE DE DATOS FUNCIONA
```

Según me explica Jaime, una promesa. Mis librerías son NPM.

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "rpserver",
  "version": "0.0.",
  "description": "Rage Roleplay Server#1.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "got": "^11.8.2",
    "log4js": "^6.1.0",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "node.js": "^0.0.1-security",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.2",
    "npm": "^8.1.2"
  }
}
```

Este es mi archivo `package.json`.

Comment: Antes que nada, ¿podrías hacer un `console.log(arrValue)` antes de llamar al `foreach`? debajo de la línea `const arrValue = misc.query(...)`. Es solo para verificar el tipo de datos que te devuelve, porque está claro que un array no es. Probablemente sea una promesa pero quiero estar seguro.

Comment: Buenas, gracias, seguí tus pasos tal cual añadiendo el `console.log(arrValue)`

Comment: Ahora en consola da el siguiente error:


`[INFO] Loading NodeJS packages...
Promise { <pending> }
[ERROR; SISTEMA DE VEHÍCULOS] TypeError: arrValue.forEach is not a function
[DONE] "RP" package has been loaded.`

Comment: Efectivamente, era una promesa. Edita tu pregunta por favor y coloca el error.. Menciona también la librería que estás usando para hacer las queries. No me suena mucho ese `misc`.

Comment: Listo, edité el mensaje. No sé mucho de librerías como tal, según me dijo un amigo es NPM.

Comment: `npm` es la herramientas con la que instalas las librerías, no las librerías como tal. ¿Puedes poner tu package.json, la sección `"dependencies`?

Comment: Listo, el contenido del archivo está en la pregunta.

Comment: Mucho me temo que la constante solo va a estar disponible en el bloque `try`. Intenta definir una variable antes y dentro actualizas el valor. pero, tratándose de una promesa, seguramente también deberás modificar la lógica del script.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, cambié totalmente la lógica del script y logré hacerlo de una forma distinta.

Answer (score 1):

1.- Puedes sacar arrValue del ambito del Try para hacer-lo visible para la otra función newFunction

2.- Cierra corchetes en la línea de Console.error

3.- También puede ser un tema de cierre de las funciones y los objetos json

```
const arrValue = misc.query('SELECT vid, modelo, pos, heading, dimension FROM vehiculos');

try {


 arrValue.forEach(data => {
    mp.vehicles.new(mp.joaat(data.modelo), new mp.Vector3(data.x, data.y, data.z)}, 
{
        heading: data.heading,
        dimension: data.dimension
    });
 //});

misc.log.info('Se han cargado exitosamente los vehículos.');

} catch (error) {
   // Aquí te falta cerrar corchetes en esta línea
   console.error('\u001b[31m[ERROR; SISTEMA DE VEHÍCULOS]] ' + error);
}

function newFunction(arrValue) {
arrValue.forEach(data => {
    mp.vehicles.new(mp.joaat(data.modelo), new mp.Vector3(data.x, data.y, data.z)}, 
{
        heading: data.heading,
        dimension: data.dimension
      });
  } // });
}
```

Comment: No estoy seguro que estés poniendo los cierres bien, comprueba-lo y ya dirás si es por los cierres cómo los he puesto aquí...